# What is the difference between "demais" and "demasiado"?

Tags: definição

As I understand it, both words are used to express "too", "too much," or "in excess" (depending on specific context).

Are these words synonymous, or is there a subtle difference I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sense of *too*, *too much*, *in excess*, **demasiado** is an adverb and an adjective, and as an adjective can take the forms demasiad**o/a/os/as**. **Demais** is an adverb only.

However, sentences with the adjective **demasiado** can be transformed into sentences with the adverb **demais** or the adverbial phrase **de mais**:

> (Especially ptPT) Passam demasiados carros nesta rua = (esp. ptBR) passam carros demais nesta rua = passam carros de mais nesta rua.

Contrary to common practice in Portuguese, *demasiados carros* sounds more natural than *carros demasiados*, but you don't say *passam demais carros nesta rua*.

As an adverb, they are indeed synonims, but are sometimes differently located in a sentence (see third example).

> Comi demasiado = comi demais = comi de mais
>
> Amo-te demais (ptBR, meaning *very much*, not *too much*).
>
> Esse bar é demasiado longe = esse bar é longe demais/de mais.

Don't ask me why you can't say *esse bar é demais/de mais longe*. It just doesn't sound right.

[Some in Portugal](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/demais-dif-de-de-mais/874) and [some in Brazil](http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/demais-ou-mais.htm) argue you can use *de mais* only for quantities (so, *carros de mais* but not *longe de mais*) and *demais* only for intensity (so, *longe demais* but not *carros demais*), but others [especially in Brazil](http://www.dicio.com.br/demais/), but [in Portugal too](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1006) say *carros demais* is just fine.

**Demais** has other unrelated uses. As an adverb it can mean *furthermore* (rarely used); as a noun or adjective *as/os demais* means *the others* or *the other (something)*. It is not interchangeable with *de mais* or *demasiado* in these senses.

Comment: *Passam carros demais nesta rua* is grammatical and perfectly okay in Brazil (we rarerely use *demasiado*).

Comment: @bfavaretto incorporei a tua informação na resposta. _Demasiado_ é suficientemente raro no Brasil para justificar dizer que _passam demasiados carros nesta rua_ é especialmente ptPT?

Comment: Acho que dá pra dizer isso sim. É muito rara ouvir isso ser dito. Escrito já é mais comum, mas dá um tom formal, empolado. Eu não sabia que em Portugal isso era o mais usado!

Comment: Fixe! Acho que fui demasiado influenciado pela grafia. *Passam carros de mais nesta rua* já me parece familiar, mas na linguagem falada não se distingue *demais* de *de mais*.

Comment: Acho que "esse bar é longe de mais" não está correto. Se não me engano só se separa quando significa "a mais".

Comment: idem para "carros demais". https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/demais-dif-de-de-mais/874

Comment: @Artefacto depende das opiniões. [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/pelourinho/demais-dif-de-de-mais/874) partilha a tua posição, [dúvidas linguísticas](http://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica.aspx?DID=1006) justifica a minha resposta. O DACL diz que _demais_ é um brasileirismo em todos os meus exemplos.